# Batch Insert with JPA and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Framework and JPA to insert beans into my database. I need to insert almost 8000 entities, and this can delay too much.

1. Why should I disable "second level cache" in Hibernate `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache false`
2. When I set a "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20" in Hibernate, will it insert my beans like this?

```
INSERT INTO VALUES (1),(2),(3)...(20);
INSERT INTO VALUES (21),(2),(3)...(40);
```

3. The documentation says: "Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if you use an identity identifier generator.". So, all my beans have this configuration:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

When I'm using this identity above, is the batch insert disabled? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate you cannot disable the session level cache. If you don't want it, use [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) . This will not cache anything.

Furthermore, Hibernate documentation specifies how to do batch insert. See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) .

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: If i can't disable the second level cache why use this property: hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache false. And i need know if i use a identity identifier my batch insert is disabled.

Comment: Second level cache and session level cache are two different things. You can disable the former but not the later

Comment: Yeah, i'm not disabling the session level cache, just second level cache (as i show in post).